# Safari: TypeError: A Proxy's 'target' should be an Object

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio-api

I'm using Web Audio and I have the following code that works fine in Chrome but not working in Safari.

```
const audioContextList = [];
(function () {
    self.AudioContext = new Proxy(self.AudioContext, {
        construct(target, args) {
            const result = new target(...args);
            audioContextList.push(result);
            return result;
        }   
    });
})();
```

In Safari, I get the following error:

> TypeError: A Proxy's 'target' should be an Object

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari 13.1 [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext) `AudioContext` with vendor prefix: webkit.

So you should access it with `self.webkitAudioContext`.
Or you can make kind of cross-browser solution

```
let AudioContext = self.AudioContext || self.webkitAudioContext;
self.AudioContext = new Proxy(AudioContext, {
  construct(target, args) {
    const result = new target(...args);
    audioContextList.push(result);
    return result;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!